# Convert Prolog functor to functor with difference lists

Tags: prolog, palindrome, dcg, difference-lists

I'm working on my homework for Prolog (SWI) but can't figure out how to get this done:

I have the functor:

```
palindrome([]).
palindrome([_]).
palindrome([A|T]) :-
      append(Middle,[A],T),
      palindrome(Middle).
```

which tells if a given list is a palindrome.

For my homework I have to write a functor `palindrome/2` without `append/3` and with difference lists.

I know a difference list is a form of `[Y|X]-X`, but I don't understand how to use this and how this can replace the append functor.

Can somebody please explain this to me?

Comment: what you call "functor" is called "predicate" in Prolog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a given list of length *n*, your solution needs some O(*n<sup>2</sup>*) inferences: *n* (actually *n/2*) for `palindrome`/1 and *i* for each `append/3` which simply searches and compares the end.

The most straight forward way to reformulate your definition uses grammars (DCGs) that are a convenient way to use difference-lists. Note that each grammar rule corresponds to a clause in your program.

```
palindrome -->
   [].
palindrome -->
   [_].
palindrome -->
   [A],
   palindrome,
   [A].

palindrome(T) :-
   phrase(palindrome,T).
```

For convenience, here is the same grammar written more compactly:

```
palindrome --> [] | [_] | [A], palindrome, [A].
```

Now, how are these grammar rules implemented? The easiest way is to look at the actual definition with `listing(palindrome)`.

```
?- listing(palindrome).
palindrome(A, A).
palindrome([_|A], A).
palindrome([C|A], D) :-
   palindrome(A, B),
   B=[C|D].
```

So this is now your definition using difference-lists.

Answer (score 2):

Just write it down yourself. You have

```
palindrome([]).           % palindrome(Z-Z).
palindrome([_]).          % palindrome([_|Z]-Z).
palindrome([A|T]) :-      % palindrome([A|T]-Z):-
  append(Middle,[A],T),   %   append(Middle-Z2,[A|Z3]-Z3,T-Z),
  palindrome(Middle).     %   palindrome(Middle-Z2).
```

Append for dif-lists is `append(A-B,B-C,A-C)`, so the append call gives us `Z2=[A|Z3], Z3=Z, Middle=T`, and so (writing out the two halves of a dif-list as two arguments for the predicate),

```
palindrome(Z,Z).
palindrome([_|Z],Z).
palindrome([A|T],Z) :-
  palindrome(T, [A|Z]).
```

Now you can run it

```
10 ?- palindrome(X,[]).

X = [] ;
X = [_G340] ;
X = [_G340, _G340] ;
X = [_G340, _G346, _G340] ;
X = [_G340, _G346, _G346, _G340] ;
....

11 ?- X=[a,b,c|_],palindrome(X,[z]).

X = [a, b, c, b, a, z] ;
X = [a, b, c, c, b, a, z] ;
X = [a, b, c, _G460, c, b, a, z] ;
X = [a, b, c, _G460, _G460, c, b, a, z] ;
....

16 ?- palindrome([1,2,2,1,0],Z).

Z = [1, 2, 2, 1, 0] ;
Z = [2, 2, 1, 0] ;
Z = [0] ;
No
```

Of course, DCG rules provide a comfortable interface to difference-lists.